# Relation between null space of a matrix and column space.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix. Then under what conditions null space of $A$ and column space of $A$ may have common elements.

My attempt: I start by taking a vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$v\in N(A)\cap Col(A)$$ where $N(A)$ is the column space of A and $Col(A)$ is column space of A. Then above means
$$v\in N(A)\implies Av=0, \ v\in Col(A)\implies v=Ay\ \text{for some}\ y.$$
Combining two we get $$A^2y=0.$$
Can I deduce anything from above? Please help.

Comment: To begin with shouldn't it be a square matrix?

Comment: Yes. I can not write $A^2$ until it is a square matrix.

Comment: But the problem is for $m$ not necessarily equal to $n$. So, I can not write $A^2$.

Comment: What "across" is pointing out is that $N(A) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\text{Col}(A) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$, so the only way a vector could be in both subspaces is if $n=m$.

Comment: @angryavian  Yes got it.

Comment: For a square matrix $A$, the following are equivalent: 1: the null space and column space have a non-trivial intersection, 2: $\operatorname{rank}(A^2) < \operatorname{rank}(A)$, 3: the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue zero is strictly greater than the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue zero.

Comment: @Mittal Note that the column-space and null space will always have the common element $0$ (if this is the only element, then the intersection is "trivial")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $A$ is square matrix and zero is an eigenvalue of $A$. If number of zero eigenvalues is $k$ and dimension of $N(A)$(also zero eigenspace) is strictly less than $k$, then we can directly say that $C(A) \cap N(A)$ has nontrivial element. It looks like the converse is true. But I could not prove yet.